How to set the print area of an array of worksheets?
Good day. I was creating a macro where i set an array of worksheets to have a certain print area.
Unfortunately the error "Runtime Error '438' Objcects dosent support this property or method" appears.
Here is my code.
Option Explicit
Dim NumberRow As String
  
Sub PrintFront()
'
' PrintFront Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

NumberRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin Panel").Range("N21").End(xlDown).Row


Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim MyArray As Variant: MyArray = Application _
.Transpose(wb.Sheets("Admin Panel").Range("N21:N" & NumberRow).Value)


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(MyArray)).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"
wb.Sheets(MyArray).PrintPreview

Here is the line that caused the error:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(MyArray)).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"

I tried using this but did not work.
wb.Sheets(MyArray).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"



You can't apply PageSetup.PrintArea setting on Sheets object/collection (multiple sheets).
Use For loop to apply PageSetup.PrintArea setting for each sheet
Validate the value of NumberRow before using it. It will be the max row number on sheet if there isn't any data under cell N21.

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim NumberRow As Long: NumberRow = wb.Sheets("Admin Panel").Range("N21").End(xlDown).Row
Dim MyArray As Variant
If NumberRow = Rows.Count Then
    MyArray = Array(wb.Sheets("Admin Panel").Range("N21").Value)
Else
    MyArray = Application _
    .Transpose(wb.Sheets("Admin Panel").Range("N21:N" & NumberRow).Value)
End If
Dim vSht As Variant
For Each vSht In MyArray
    wb.Sheets(vSht).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"
Next
wb.Sheets(MyArray).PrintPreview


Set Print Area for Multiple Sheets

The last part (snippet) in my answer to your previous question illustrates why Sheets(Array(MyArray)) doesn't work. It has to be Sheets(MyArray).

A Quick Fix
Sub PrintFront()
'
' PrintFront Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Admin Panel")
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("N21", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    ' The following will fail if 'N21' is the only populated cell!!!
    'Set rg = ws.Range("N21", ws.Range("N21").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim MyArray As Variant: MyArray = Application.Transpose(rg.Value)
  
    ' Although the following line works...
    'wb.Sheets(MyArray).PrintPreview
    ' ... the following one doesn't:
    'wb.Sheets(MyArray).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"

    ' Assuming all sheets exist and are worksheets.
  
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets(MyArray)
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"
    Next ws

    wb.Worksheets(MyArray).PrintPreview

End Sub

An Improvement

Since the previous would fail if a sheet doesn't exist or it is a chart, I would suggest you use the following safer procedure.

Sub PrintFrontSafer()
'
' PrintFront Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Admin Panel")
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("N21", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim MyArray As Variant: MyArray = Application.Transpose(rg.Value)
    
    Dim SheetName As Variant ' must be a Variant
    
    For Each SheetName In MyArray
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if doesn't exist or if chart
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetName) ' a chart has no print area!!!
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "C4:AF45"
            Set ws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        'Else ' it doesn't exist or it's a chart; do nothing
        End If
    Next SheetName

    ' Assuming all sheets exist.
    wb.Sheets(MyArray).PrintPreview

End Sub

